# Run same Jenkins job with different parameters sequentially

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a jenkins job A which takes let's say have param `foo` allowed value of foo are (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). Now I want to make a jenkins job B which runs job A with param `foo` with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 sequentially. i.e Job B will be Job A 7 times with param `foo` all value sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Job B') {
            steps {
                script {
                   def foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                   foo.each { val ->
                    build job:'JobA' , parameters:[ string(name: 'fooInJobA',value: val)], wait: true
                       
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```